# Using Wordpress and Codeigniter in one website

Tags: php, wordpress, codeigniter, frameworks, content-management-system

Is it possible to use WordPress as the CMS but all of contents will be displayed using CodeIgniter?

What I want to know also if I can use the functions of WordPress by simply including this wp-blog-header.php in the CodeIgniter.

Do you think guys this idea will work?

Probably one of the function I really need is apply_filters().

Comment: What exactly is going to be displayed by CI and couldn't be by WP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the wordpress headers on a codeigniter site once, and there were a lot of conflicts with global functions like site_url that had to be manually resolved (by renaming those functions in the codeigniter core)

It was a mess, and I wouldn't recommend it if you can get away with it.

You might be better off querying the same database and building new functionality in codeigniter using the same data.

But if you still want to do it, you can do something like this:

```
// in codeigniter index.php
require_once( '../wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

Then (in your header view, for example):

```
if(function_exists('get_header')) 
{
    get_header(); // will echo the wordpress header
} else { 
    //html code for your header ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html dir="ltr" lang="en-US">
    <!-- etc... -->
<?php } ?>
```

And you should see the wordpress header, at least once you solve all the errors caused by including it.  There's also a `get_footer()` function for the footer.

Good luck